# Have multiple divs inline using the full width of the page (like continuous text.)

Tags: html, css

I got me a issue with two divs for some reason they do not want to show their content inline.

I uploaded the full code in question to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w76pswwn/

As you can see in the fiddle those

```
        <div class="storymode inline">
          <span class="action-Cutscene">
            <p>
              On a cold winter night a epic tale between Blanka and Colossus came to a end during a powerful battle on top of a New York City Skyscraper.&nbsp;
            </p>
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="storymode inline">
          <span class="action-Cutscene">
            <p>
              On a cold winter night a epic tale between Blanka and Colossus came to a end during a powerful battle on top of a New York City Skyscraper.&nbsp;
            </p>
          </span>
        </div>
```

#### display like this:

On a cold winter night a epic tale between Blanka and Colossus came to a end during a powerful battle on top of a New York City Skyscraper.

On a cold winter night a epic tale between Blanka and Colossus came to a end during a powerful battle on top of a New York City Skyscraper.

#### but i want:

On a cold winter night a epic tale between Blanka and Colossus came to a end during a powerful battle on top of a New York City Skyscraper. On a cold winter night a epic tale between Blanka and Colossus came to a end during a powerful battle on top of a New York City Skyscraper.

I tried `inline, inline-block` and `float` but I am missing something. But what?

Thanks in advance for helping!

PS: I cannot change the HTML Structure. At least not easily! So please make suggestions that can work with this structure.

Comment: Having a `p` inside a `span` is invalid as the `span` is an inline element and `p` is a block element, and inline element should not have block elements as children

Comment: @LGSon Yeah but as it happens the Editor that creates this kind of code in Joomla doesn't give a .... about that. That's why I said it ain't easy to change the HTML output. But your warning is appreciated and useful!

Comment: Then switch the Editor! ... Editors that does not create valid code should be banned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `p` elements have to be `inline` otherwise they'll override the property.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/byuqbqLL/2/

Comment: So basically everything needs to be inline. What if there is a img element and other things like that should I add the class inline then as well? Thanks for giving the fiddle and answering.

Comment: Thank you for the information and the help it is highly appreciated. I upvoted your question.

Answer (score 1):

give p and .inline display: inline;

```
p {
display: inline;
}
.inline {
display: inline 
}
```

like so: https://jsfiddle.net/w76pswwn/2/

Comment: Your answer is almost the same as the one from guavacat but you are not adding the class to the span. Is this because a span is naturally already a inline element?

Comment: Yes span is default inline but the way I did it had no reasoning. The class add makes sense since you could have lots of p elements and likely don't want to inline all of them.

Comment: Thanks for that I always want to know why choosing certain items. Your answers are highly appreciated and the fiddle as well. I am going to check in my life environment which one works best.

Answer (score 1):

Having a `p` inside a `span` is invalid as the `span` is an inline element and `p` is a block element, and inline element should not have block elements as children.

Either change your `p` to a `span` or `span` to a `div`. If the latter you need to let the `div` and `p` be displayed as inline, as in below sample

*If you suffer from **can't change the markup** phenomenon, below CSS will also work on your existing markup*

```css
.inline { display:inline; }

.inline div, .inline p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="storymode inline">
  <div class="action-Cutscene">
    <p>
      On a cold winter night a epic tale between Blanka and Colossus came to a end during a powerful battle on top of a New York City Skyscraper.&nbsp;
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="storymode inline">
  <div class="action-Cutscene">
    <p>
      On a cold winter night a epic tale between Blanka and Colossus came to a end during a powerful battle on top of a New York City Skyscraper.&nbsp;
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```